# How can I migrate my Android project to Androidx?

Tags: android, androidx

I have to migrate my current android project to androidx, because I have to change a deprecated code.

I want to add 'androidx.core:core:1.0.1' to the project dependencies but it doesn't work because it is not compatible with my current dependencies.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Thank you !

My build.gradle now is:

```
    implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.5'
    implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'
```

Comment: have you tried running the wizard from inside android studio ?

Comment: With the option Refractor-> Migrate-> androidx it doesn't work :(

Comment: [Try manually replacing the libraries](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate). Look for correspondent library and replace it with your current support libs.

Comment: why did the Android Studio migration wizard not work?

Answer (score 3):

With Android Studio 3.2 and higher, you can quickly migrate an existing project to use AndroidX by selecting Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX from the menu bar.

If you have any Maven dependencies that have not been migrated to the AndroidX namespace, the Android Studio build system also migrates those dependencies for you when you set the following two flags to true in your gradle.properties file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

To migrate an existing project that does not use any third-party libraries with dependencies that need converting, you can set the android.useAndroidX flag to true and the `android.enableJetifier` flag to false.